# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded in a body of POST request using android annotations and resttemplate

Tags: java, android, spring, resttemplate, android-annotations

my interface looks as follows:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "https://myurl.com", converters = { GsonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface CommunicatonInterface
{
@Get("/tables/login")
public Login login(Param param);
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate();
}
```

The question is what i supposed to put as a param to get in body simply:

```
login=myName&password=myPassword&key=othereKey
```

without escaping, brackets or quota.

I've try to pass a string and i just get:
`"login=myName&password=myPassword&key=othereKey"` but it is wrong because of quota signs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to post `login` and `password` parameters from a form to your method.

For this, you should ensure you have the following steps:

1. Create a login form which has input text fields with `login` and `password` as names.
2. Make sure the `form` has a `POST` method, you don't really want to have user's credentials in the URL as get params, but if you use case needs you to do it, you can.
3. In your `Interface`, instead of using `GsonHttpMessageConverter` you should be using `FormHttpMessageConverter`. This converter accepts and returns content with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the correct `content-type` for form submissions.
4. Your `Param` class should have fields which have the same name as the input text fields. In your case, `login` and `password`. After you do this, request parameters posted in the form will be available in the `param` instance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure to include FormHttpMessageConverter.class in your converters list.
2. Instead of using a Param type for sending the data, use a MultiValueMap implementation (such as LinkedMultiValueMap) or make your Param class extend LinkedMultiValueMap.

Example extending LinkedMultiValueMap:

```java
@Rest(converters = {FormHttpMessageConverter.class, MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface RestClient extends RestClientRootUrl {
    @Post("/login")
    LoginResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest);
}


public class LoginRequest extends LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> {
    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        add("username", username);
        add("password", password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple converters because based on the object passed in, it will choose a converter for you. That said if you pass in a MultiValueMap it will for some reason add it to the headers because Android Annotations creates a HttpEntity. If you extend MultiValueMap as Ricardo suggested it will work.